# Coredata attribute join

Tags: core-data, cocoa-bindings

Hi I have a Core data entity that has a few attributes like displayName, serverName and portNumber.

I want the serverName and portNumber to be user editable. I want the display name to be auto generated using the serverName and portNumber values - something like "Server @ Port"

What is the best way of implementing the displayName attribute ? Is there anything like trigger in Core Data that would auto populate this attribute ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply add a method to your managed object subclass without the need to save this information again the database.

```
-(NSString*)displayName {
   return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ : %@", self.serverName, self.portNumber];
}
```

---

**Tipp**: use a separate file with a *category* on your subclass. In this way, in case the object model changes, you can use Xcode to generate the subclass again without overwriting your custom code.

Comment: Since this is tagged as a bindings question, adding `keyPathsForValuesAffectingDisplayName` would make this code work for bindings as long as they do not try to set display name.  To some extent [Registering dependent keys](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueObserving/Articles/KVODependentKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002179-BAJEAIEE) is the "trigger" @Silican is looking for.

Comment: Thank you for this perspective - spot on.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the response Mundi and stevesilva. This is what I have been needing for my code.